# Where is Photostream data stored?

Tags: ios, photo-stream

I don't have to be connected to the internet to view them on my phone. Is it storing the current ones on my device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main store of the Photo Stream is on iCloud. Local copies of the latest 1000 photos in your Photo Stream are stored on your iDevices. Photo Stream pictures can also be downloaded into your iPhoto and/or Aperture photo libraries, or onto a designated folder on your Windows PC. Photos are purged from the Photostream cloud store after thirty days, so be certain that photos you want to save are downloaded to your computer, or saved to your iOS device camera roll on a regular basis.

ᔥ Apple: [iCloud — Photo Stream](http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/photo-stream.html)
ᔥ Macworld: [iCloud:What you need to know](http://www.macworld.com/article/1160380/icloud_what_you_need_to_know.html)

*Note that you now have the ability to delete individual photos from Photo Stream* Macworld's *statement to the contrary was true at the time of publication.*

Answer (score 2):

They are stored on your iPhone. You can find them in the Photos app.
It's a smart album filled with photos taken in the last 30 days.

**Comment by Jaberg:** (thanks!)

> The Photo Stream smart album on an iOS device will contain the 1000
>   latest photos. The main "cloud store"will contain the photos from the
>   last 30 days and those photos will all be viewable/downloadable from a
>   computer.

[image]

Comment: So iPhoto on my Mac downloads them from my device? And, I can free up space on my phone by turning off Photostream then? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: iPhoto download the photos from the iCloud. And you can't save any space turning off Photostream, since it are the same photos as your Camera Roll. Hence the smart album

Comment: Minor correction: The Photo Stream *smart album* on an iOS device will contain the 1000 latest photos. The main "cloud store"will contain the photos from the last 30 days and those photos will all be viewable/downloadable from a computer.

Comment: Good correction! I'll add it to my answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also regarding your comment on saving space. You may not be able to save space on the capturing device (though you always have the option to delete photos from the camera roll) but you can save space on your other iOS devices by turning off Photo Stream. I might not want *every* photo I take with my iPhone immediately sync'd to my iPad... and on the capturing device, I'm not certain that Photo Stream uses the camera roll copy. Do you have a citation for that? *If I delete an appropriate photo from camera roll it is still available on Photo Stream*.

Comment: When you take a picture with your PhotoStream turned on, your iDevice uses a link to upload it to iCloud. And the PhotoStream album uses the linklist in your iCloud. So, you're right (again) when it comes to saving space. But on your original device, as far as I know, you can't save space by turning off Photostream

Comment: You would "save space" by not receiving the Photo Stream photos from *other* devices, but we're not getting more into semantics than anything else.