# Does PhotoStream sync to my Mac when iPhoto is not open?

Tags: photos.app, photo-stream

The only application I have on my Mac that works with PhotoStream is iPhoto. I'm wondering if my Mac grabs the images from PhotoStream constantly or if it only downloads them when I launch an application that uses PhotoStream (such as iPhoto).

Comment: I did some research yesterday to find a way to easily get to them as well http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45316/is-there-a-way-to-access-iclouds-photo-stream-from-the-finder-similar-to-windo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes!** A process called `PhotoStreamAgent` runs at login, and idles in the background, downloading new photos when they're uploaded to your Photo Stream.

[image]

There exist both `/Applications/Aperture.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/PhotoStreamAgent.app` and `/Applications/iPhoto.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/PhotoStreamAgent.app`, indicating that this background-downloading behavior works no matter which application you use to manage your photo library.

(And as Asmus points out, photos are stored in `~/Library/Application Support/iLifeAssetManagement/assets`)

Comment: This is also why iCloud in System Preferences also requires you to have one of the two installed, instead of it being installed in /System/Library/ or the like.

Comment: That's good to know, but I assume that `~/Library/Application Support/iLifeAssetManagement/assets` only stores the _Photo Stream_ photos (as opposed to photos contained in your iPhoto library) - which are limited to the most recent _1000_.  Say you don't start `iPhoto` for a long time, and you've snapped more than 1000 photos in the meantime: would you then miss out on some of the photos? Or do the agents perform ongoing imports from that location?

Answer (score 2):

The photos are "constantly" downloaded to your Mac, and stored in subfolders within `~/Library/Application\ Support/iLifeAssetManagement/assets/sub`.