# Access My Photo Stream photos via finder

Tags: photo-stream

I have searched all over, and can't seem to find if it is possible to access "My Photo Stream" photos via finder. It seems that this [used to be possible](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45316/is-there-a-way-to-access-iclouds-photo-stream-from-the-finder-similar-to-windo?rq=1) with the previous incarnation of Photo Streams, but I can't find anything dealing with the new version.

I'm currently using a tool called photostream2folder, which works great, but it is a black box. I'd like to do some scripting of the process, and for that I need to know how to access these photos directly from the stream.

It seems that this used to be the path to use "/Users/username/Library/Application Support/iLifeAssetManagement/assets", but it is no longer the case.