# Is there any way to access the Photo Stream outside of Photos.app in El Capitan

Tags: macos, icloud, photo-stream

This is basically a duplicate of [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45316/is-there-a-way-to-access-iclouds-photo-stream-from-the-finder-similar-to-windo), which was answered for prior versions, but whose answer is no longer applicable in El Capitan.

My question includes programmatically: if there's a programmatic / Cocoa way to access the Photo Stream contents stored (somewhere?) on your computer, then perhaps we can build a filesystem-in-userspace or similar to access them?

Comment: I have not heard of Apple releasing an SDK for Photostream (which is very unfortunate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've answered this for myself: **iCloud Photo Library photos are buried in subfolders of `"~/Pictures/*.photoslibrary/Masters"` on El Capitan!**

Using a `savedSearch`, the same approach as was popular under Yosemite and earlier, we can create a Finder folder that lists, chronologically, your Photo Stream. The XML version [is here](https://gist.github.com/ELLIOTTCABLE/4530ed8d0e5344f6e7ea) (you may have to modify some paths), or you can download [my pre-compiled version](http://ell.io/i1kZ5t) instead:

[image: iCloud Photos smart-folder]

Ta-da!

[image: List of iCloud Photos files in the Finder]